# How to use CodeVariableDeclaraionStament to declare Arrays

Tags: c#

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement cvds = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(p.ParameterType, p.Name,
                       new CodePrimitiveExpression(INTARR()));
```

Consider the above code. 
and when i run my project in debug mode,these are the values that get stored in p.ParameterType  and p.Name.

```
p.ParameterType = {Name = "Int32[]" FullName = "System.Int32[]"}
p.Name = "x"
```

and INTARR() is a method that returns an Array of Integers.

but i get the error,
"Invalid Primitive Type: System.Int32[]. Consider using CodeObjectCreateExpression."

How can i use CodeObjectCreateExpression for the above code,i.e I want to pass an Array of integers in CodeVariableDeclarationStatement.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not primitive.  You need to use CodeArrayCreateExpression:

```
Int32[] ints = INTARR();
CodeExpression[] intExps = new CodePrimitiveExpression[ints.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
   intExps[i] = new CodePrimitiveExpression(ints[i]);
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement cvds = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(
   "Int32[]", "x", new CodeArrayCreateExpression("Int32", intExps));
```

Answer (score 0):

based on this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/e2c984ae-93e4-4d3c-8086-cbcd877b4eec/) I think it should be like this

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement cvds = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(typeof(Int32[]), "x",
                       new CodePrimitiveExpression(INTARR()));
```

So maybe this?:

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement cvds = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(typeof(Int32[], "x",
                       new CodePrimitiveExpression(INTARR()));                     

p.ParameterType = typeof(Int32);
p.Name = "x";
```